# How does IIS know if a request is webforms or MVC? (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller, webforms, request

Short question:

How does IIS know if a request is webforms or MVC?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer: IIS doesn't know; ASP.NET knows via HTTP Handlers

Both WebForms and MVC are built on top of ASP.NET, and both use HTTP Handlers to deal with per-request execution:

- WebForms has `.aspx` files mapped to the [`PageHandlerFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagehandlerfactory.aspx)
- MVC integrates into the [`Routing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) infrastructure as an [`IRouteHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.aspx) implementation. Routes is notified of requests via the [`UrlRoutingHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutinghandler.aspx)

ASP.NET, in turn, is notified of all requests in IIS7+ and via mapped file extensions in IIS6-

Answer (score 3):

IIS doesn't know that. An url is parsed by ASP.NET (which is the base of both webforms as MVC) according to the settings in the web.config.